# How to remove inline style

Tags: jquery-ui

I use jQuery UI draggable droppable features. When I drop one element inside the other I need to remove an inline style of the parent, which currently has 
a class with float: left. I need to remove that attribute. I tried adding

```
.css("float","none")
```

but my page fell appart. Is there an alternative to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to limit the amount of css manipulation through javascript...this problem you're encountering being one of the reasons.  A better idea would be to set and remove classes on the element that requires the CSS change.

```
.float{
   float: left;
}


$(element).addClass('float');
$(element).removeClass('float');
```

This method doesn't add inline css.